# Aggregating Data with OVER PARTITION by date

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, math

Continuation of this question:
[Postgresql: calculate share of total investment per investor, per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597821/postgresql-calculate-share-of-total-investment-per-investor-per-day)

Following on from this question, I'd like to have a query which will provide me with daily stats based on data for multiple investors.

For example, let's say I have 4 investors and I want daily stats for two of them combined. I'd end up with a table which looks something like this:

| date | total_profit | total_investment | user_investment | investment_share | user_share | user_profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 500 | 10000 | 5000 | 50.00 | 38.2865 | 95.71625 |
| 2021-01-02 | 200 | 10000 | 5000 | 50.00 | 38.2865 | 38.2865 |
| 2021-01-03 | 185 | 15000 | 2500 | 16.66 | 16.3336 | 15.1085 |
| 2021-01-04 | 175 | 15000 | 3000 | 20.00 | 11.2478 | 9.8418 |
| 2021-01-05 | 229 | 15000 | 3000 | 20.00 | 11.2478 | 12.8787 |

Here's a descripion of each column:

**date**: single date corresponding to profit in daily_stats table

**total_profit**: the value in the profit column for the dated daily_stats row

**total_investment**: the combined value of all investments for the current date

**user_investment**: the combined value of the selected users' investments for the current date

**investment_share**: the combined value of the 'percent' column of the investments for the selected users, proportional to the investment amount. I think the formula for this value would be:

```
(i.amount / (SUM(i.amount) over (partition by s.date))) * i.percent
```

for example, if I was looking at data for two users who each had one investment within my date range, I'd have to calcualte the combined value of the percentage columns like so:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **amount** | **percent** |
| 2 | 500 | 20 |
| 3 | 200 | 45 |

( (A2 / (A2 + A3) ) * B2) + ( (A3 / (A2 + A3) ) * B3)

or alternatively

(B2 * A2 + B3 * A3) / (A2 + A3)

but I think doing it that way might be more tricky with the way the current query is set up. I'm using a spreadsheet to mock this up btw so it may be useful for you to copy/paste this into a google sheet or something.

**user_share**: the percentage of the profit that investors will take based on the size of their combined investment as a proportion of the size of the total investment.

```
e.g. (500 + 200) / 15000 = user_share = 0.046 (4.6%)
```

**user_profit** finally this would just simply be total_profit * investment_share * user_share

I'm sure I've made lots more basic mathematical errors again and I don't have fatigue to blame it on anymore because it's lunchtime where I am now :P

here's the updated fiddle with a crappy attempt at what I need: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1DFJKzMs8SuYeVAUYcHU9/11

Comment: I'm lost.  Is the table the data you are starting with?  Is it your desired results?  Having both is really helpful.

Comment: The table is my desired results, data can be found in the db-fiddle at the bottom of the post. This post is actually a continuation from a previous question where a helpful user suggested I set up a new question. But any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying you just want the SUM of the user_share and SUM of the user_profit column (separately) per day over the specified list of users.  Is that all?  We can just wrap the initial solution in a `WITH clause` term and perform the SUMs.

Answer (score 0):

The original query already provides the basic detail per day for each users.  No need to rehash that calculation.  Just wrap the query in a CTE term.

Here are the columns produced by the original query:

```
| date       | profit | user_id | amount | percent | total_inv | user_profit |
```

It's not clear what you want to do with percent.  I don't think that one can be easily aggregated, if you remember what that value represents.

Something like this (with total_share):

```
WITH query1 AS (
  SELECT s.date, s.profit
       , i.user_id, i.amount, i.percent
       , SUM(i.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY s.date) AS total_inv
       , ROUND(s.profit * (i.percent / 100.0) * i.amount / SUM(i.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY s.date), 2) AS user_profit
       , ROUND((1.0 * i.amount / (SUM(i.amount) over (partition by s.date))) * i.percent, 2) AS user_share
    FROM daily_stats AS s
    JOIN investments AS i
      ON s.date BETWEEN i.start_date AND i.end_date
   WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-05'
     )
SELECT date
     , MAX(profit) AS profit
     , MAX(total_inv) AS total_inv
     , SUM(user_profit) AS total_profit
     , SUM(user_share) AS total_share
  FROM query1
 WHERE user_id IN (1, 4)
 GROUP BY date
;
```

With result from fiddle:

[image: Quick view of the fiddle result]

Working test case:
[Test case with PG V3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b187983802959e48bc6a1ed586894fa)

Updated your test case here:
[Your test case updated](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1DFJKzMs8SuYeVAUYcHU9/12)

Comment: I didn't include the new user_share calculation.  But that should be fairly simple to add.

Comment: @Dioralop user_share / total calculation included. I think your user_share example calculation might be incorrect.  I believe you missed the multiplication by the percent for that user.  Feel free to explain.